# What is the best approach to inserting or updating an integer using stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table called Employees.

This table is updated daily with a scheduled job from Active Directory.

We currently have the following stored procedure that checks if a particular employee exists in the Employee table.

If yes, update the rest of the employee records in that table.

If no, then insert the employee record into that Employee table.

In order to determine whether an employee exists in Employee table or not, employees are required to FIRST enter their employeeID. This is not an auto-generated ID. It is imported into the Employee table along with rest of employee records from Active Directory if that employee record exists in Active Directory.

The issue we are having is that we are not able insert a new employee record into Employee table. Neither are we able to update the record.

We kept getting the message that:

***Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'employeeID', table 'Employees'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.The statement has been terminated.***

I suspect the issue is with my stored procedure but not sure what the issue is.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is my stored proc and the code I am using to try to invoke it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Employees] 
 @FullName       varchar(75),
 @address     varchar(100),
 @city        varchar(50),
 @state       varchar(50),
 @zip         varchar(50),
 @eid  int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  begin tran
  if exists (select * from Employees where employeeID = @eid)
   begin
    UPDATE Employees SET [empFullName] = @FullName
      ,[Address] = @address
      ,[City] = @city
      ,[State] = @state
      ,[Zip] = @zip where employeeID = @eid
    end
    else
    begin
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees]
           ([empFullName]
           ,[Address]
           ,[City]
           ,[State]
           ,[Zip]
           ,[employeeID])
     VALUES
           (@FullName
           ,@address
           ,@city
           ,@state
           ,@zip
           ,@eid)

  SET @eid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  end
  commit tran
END



            int eid = 0;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Employees", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", txtfname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtfaddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtcity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", ddlstates.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", txtfzip.Text);
            SqlParameter employeeID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@eid", SqlDbType.Int);
            employeeID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            eid = Convert.ToInt32(employeeID.Value);
```

I need to grab this employeeID after insert or update and insert it in other tables.

Comment: Is employeeID an identity column? Or a standard INT? Presumably you want it to be unique. @eid is an output parameter, so using it in the insert is going to give you a hard time, and, you aren't getting the MAX ID or anything like that. Your use of SCOPE_IDENTITY suggests employeeID is an identity column, if it is, then you don't have to include it in the INSERT as SQL will take care of it.

Comment: @Leonidas199x, as stated in my original, it is not an auto-increment id. So, no, it is not an identity see. It is imported into the Employee table along with rest of employee data.

Comment: @Kenny Why are you using SCOPE_IDENTITY then? I don't think that does what you think it does, if you are not using an identity column.

Comment: Yeah the SCOPE_IDENTITY() call is really confusing. Having eid as an output parameter is confusing too. Either it's an identity that does in fact need to be output, or it isn't, in which case it has no point being output.

Comment: I get more confused the more I read it. You know the employeeID as it comes from AD, so why not just pass that in with the rest of the info? Isn't all you care about if the user exists or you need to create a new one? Why do you need the output parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MERGE (starting with Sql Server 2008)

```sql
MERGE Employees AS target  
USING (SELECT @eid, 
              @fullName, 
              @address, 
              @city,
              @state, 
              @zip) AS source (eid, fullName, address, city, state, zip)  
ON (target.employeeID = source.eid)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE SET 
        empFullName = source.fullName,
        Address = source.address,
        City = source.city,
        State = source.state,
        Zip = source.zip
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (employeeID, empFullName, Address, City, State, Zip)  
    VALUES (source.eid, 
            source.fullName, 
            source.address, 
            source.city, 
            source.state, 
            source.zip)  
OUTPUT inserted.employeeID; -- return updated or inserted Id
```

Comment: I haven't used Merge before. Is this still part of the stored proc?

Comment: You can use it in stored procedures

Comment: How did I not know about `MERGE`?  This is going to change my life...  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is simply you are not passing the employee id in as it should be. Pass it in with the rest of the code, and discard the output and SCOPE_IDENTITY. Amend you C# to add it to the stored proc along with the rest and it should be fine. Also, not sure of the point of using BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN without a try/catch, to either commit, or rollback. Otherwise it is just getting committed with or without:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [DBO].[USP_EMPLOYEES] 
 @FULLNAME       VARCHAR(75),
 @ADDRESS       VARCHAR(100),
 @CITY          VARCHAR(50),
 @STATE         VARCHAR(50),
 @ZIP           VARCHAR(50),
 @EMPLOYEEID    INT     ,
 @EID           INT 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  BEGIN TRAN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEEID = @EID)
       BEGIN
        UPDATE EMPLOYEES 
        SET [EMPFULLNAME] = @FULLNAME
          ,[ADDRESS] = @ADDRESS
          ,[CITY] = @CITY
          ,[STATE] = @STATE
          ,[ZIP] = @ZIP 
         WHERE EMPLOYEEID = @EID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO [DBO].[EMPLOYEES]
                   ([EMPFULLNAME]
                   ,[ADDRESS]
                   ,[CITY]
                   ,[STATE]
                   ,[ZIP]
                   ,[EMPLOYEEID])
             VALUES
                   (@FULLNAME
                   ,@ADDRESS
                   ,@CITY
                   ,@STATE
                   ,@ZIP
                   ,@EID)

      END
  COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
...
  @eid  int
as
begin
...
  SET @eid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees]
           ([empFullName]
           ,[Address]
           ,[City]
           ,[State]
           ,[Zip]
           ,[employeeID])
     VALUES
           (@FullName
           ,@address
           ,@city
           ,@state
           ,@zip
           ,@eid)
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly, explain what the issue is, and how your code fixes it. Don't just provide a raw code dump.